# How can I get an API's JSON data from a Reqwest response?

Tags: rust, reqwest

I want to get the data from an API:

```
extern crate reqwest;

use std::io::Read;

pub fn main() {
    let mut response = reqwest::get("https://api.fcoin.com/v2/market/ticker/ftbtc")
        .expect("Failed to send request");
    let mut buf = String::new();
    response
        .read_to_string(&mut buf)
        .expect("Failed to read response");
    println!("{}", buf);
}
```

The output is

```
{
  "status": 0,
  "data": {
    "ticker": [
      0.00006173,
      500,
      0.00006173,
      44411.28,
      0.00006174,
      917.98,
      0.00008033,
      0.00008654,
      0.00006026,
      7144217252.9,
      554239.7346328925
    ],
    "type": "ticker.ftbtc",
    "seq": 2995173
  }
}
```

Can I transfer the `buf` or response into a key => value style `Vec` or array?

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [How do I parse a JSON File?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30292752/155423) (specifically the answer using Serde. If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.