# How do you read a YAML file in Rust?

Tags: rust, yaml, rust-crates

I've poked the [serde-yaml](https://github.com/dtolnay/serde-yaml) and [yaml-rust](https://github.com/chyh1990/yaml-rust) crates a bit, but I haven't seen any examples.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

[serde-yaml's documentation](https://docs.rs/serde_yaml/0.8.7/serde_yaml/) has the following 4 functions:

- [`from_reader`](https://docs.rs/serde_yaml/0.8.7/serde_yaml/fn.from_reader.html) — Deserialize an instance of type `T` from an IO stream of YAML.
- [`from_slice`](https://docs.rs/serde_yaml/0.8.7/serde_yaml/fn.from_slice.html) —  Deserialize an instance of type `T` from bytes of YAML text.
- [`from_str`](https://docs.rs/serde_yaml/0.8.7/serde_yaml/fn.from_str.html) — Deserialize an instance of type `T` from a string of YAML text.
- [`from_value`](https://docs.rs/serde_yaml/0.8.7/serde_yaml/fn.from_value.html) — Interpret a `serde_yaml::Value` as an instance of type `T`.

Using `from_reader` as an example:

```
use serde_yaml; // 0.8.7

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let f = std::fs::File::open("something.yaml")?;
    let d: String = serde_yaml::from_reader(f)?;
    println!("Read YAML string: {}", d);
    Ok(())
}
```

**something.yaml**:

```
"I am YAML"
```

You can deserialize into the looser-typed [`Value`](https://docs.rs/serde_yaml/0.8.7/serde_yaml/enum.Value.html) if you don't know your format (`String` in this example), but be sure to read the [Serde guide](https://serde.rs/) for full details of how to do type-directed serialization and deserialization instead.

See also:

- [How do I parse a JSON File?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49950214/155423)
- [Deserializing TOML into vector of enum with values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48641541/deserializing-toml-into-vector-of-enum-with-values)

In general, using *any* Serde format is pretty much the same as all the rest.

Comment: This example returns `Error: Scan(ScanError { mark: Marker { index: 7, line: 2, col: 4 }, info: "mapping values are not allowed in this context" })`; does anything changed since your answer @Shepmaster ?

Comment: @Ben sounds like your YAML file is malformed or doesn't match with the type that you are attempting to parse.

Comment: humm sorry (rust beginner here); i was more trying to parse key/value'd yaml file (a one liner like `a: 'b'` ) to get started). but i guess it goes well beyond the scope of the initial issue here

Comment: @Ben that's what "You can deserialize into the looser-typed Value if you don't know your format " and "read the Serde guide for full details of how to do type-directed" refer to.

Answer (score 14):

This example uses the [yaml_rust crate](https://crates.io/crates/yaml-rust)

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use yaml_rust::yaml::{Hash, Yaml};
use yaml_rust::YamlLoader;

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, Yaml");
    let file = "./etc/my_yaml_file.yaml";
    load_file(file);
}

fn load_file(file: &str) {
    let mut file = File::open(file).expect("Unable to open file");
    let mut contents = String::new();

    file.read_to_string(&mut contents)
        .expect("Unable to read file");

    let docs = YamlLoader::load_from_str(&contents).unwrap();

    // iterate / process doc[s] ..
}
```

Comment: Also consider [`std::fs::read_to_string`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.read_to_string.html) to read the file contents.

Answer (score 4):

The [answer from Shepmaster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53243962/42223) is great if you want to do it properly. Here's a complete example to get started with.

`data['foo']['bar'].as_str()` returns an `Option<str>`.

```rust
fn example() -> Result<String> {
    let f = std::fs::File::open("something.yaml")?;
    let data: serde_yaml::Value = serde_yaml::from_reader(f)?;
    data["foo"]["bar"]
        .as_str()
        .map(|s| s.to_string())
        .ok_or(anyhow!("Could not find key foo.bar in something.yaml"))
}
```